# Unable to bind dependency properties of a custom user control

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, binding

I'm trying to create a legend control that is a databound set of stack panels and am having significant issues with getting data binding to work.  After many searches I was able to get binding to work on a standard control defined in my datatemplate.   However, when I use *exactly* the same binding to set the value on my custom control, my dependency property doesn't get set.  Here is the relevant XAML

**EDIT**  I changed my complex custom item with a simple user control that just has a button - same effect - thanks for the help

```
       <StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">

    <TextBlock Text="Legend:" />
    <ItemsControl x:Name="tStack" ItemsSource="{Binding LegendItems}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Content="{Binding ItemLabel}"  />
                    <pxsc:TestItem  ItemLabel="{Binding ItemLabel}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>

        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    <!--       <pxsc:PXLegendItem ItemColor="Green" ItemLabel="TextLabel"/> -->

</StackPanel>
```

// TestItem

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightControls.TestItem"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400"
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"             >

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Button Content="{Binding ItemLabel}" />
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

TestItem code behind

```
    public partial class TestItem : UserControl
{
    public TestItem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    #region ItemLabel
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemLabelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemLabel", typeof(string), typeof(TestItem), 
new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnItemLabelPropertyChanged)));

    public string ItemLabel
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ItemLabelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemLabelProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnItemLabelPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d,
 DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public static void SetItemLabel(DependencyObject obj, string val)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ItemLabelProperty, val);
    }
    public static double GetItemLabel(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (double)obj.GetValue(ItemLabelProperty);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

In my sample code, I populate LegendItems with 3 objects.  The ItemsControl creates three buttons that are correctly labeled and three of my legenditem controls without any label set.

If I uncomment the last line I do see that the additional control correctly accepts the TextLabel value.

I thought this was a fairly "by-the-book" implementation so I'm surprised that it's not working and any assitance is gretly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post your code for PXLegendItem (both XAML and C#)?

Comment: Well you've shown code that pretty much works and not shown the code that should be working but isn't namely the implemenation of the `ItemLabel` property.

Comment: What's interesting is that if I put an invalid binding, the ItemLabel on PXLegendItem is set to an empty string, but if I put the valid binding, it's not set at all.

Comment: I've updated the sample with a user control that exhibits the bad behavior - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a stab in the dark, you haven't implemented the `ItemLabel` as a dependency property or if you have its not be implemented properly.  If the latter then edit your question with the relevent code.

**Edit**

Since your control assigns itself to the `DataContext` any existing `DataContext` from its ancestors will be ignored.  Remove your assignment to the `DataContext`.  Change your inner xaml to:-

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Button Content="{Binding Parent.ItemLabel, ElementName=LayoutRoot}" />
</Grid>
```

That should get it working. BTW do you really need `GetItemLabel` and `SetItemLabel` static methods?  Those are usually included for Attached properties but not standard dependency properties.

Comment: Thanks - that worked - I figured that the ItemsControl would override any DataContext set in the DataTemplate control.  REgarding the static methods - I copied a DP pattern from the documentation, so that's why those are there.